# QtScriptEngine: Access child object from an object in script

Tags: c++, qt, qtscript, qt5.1

I want to access the storage object inside my CoreProxy instance from a script as below:

```
CoreProxy proxy(core);
QScriptEngine engine;
QScriptValue coreInScript = engine.newQObject(&proxy);
engine.globalObject().setProperty("acq", coreInScript);
engine.evaluate("acq.storage.start()");
```

But QScriptEngine gives me this error back:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'acq.storage' [undefined] is not an object.
```

Here is my CoreProxy class:

```
class CoreProxy : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Core *_core;

public:
    CoreProxy(Core *core);

    StorageProxy *storage;

public slots:
    // Public slots for javascript interactions
    QString init(QString acqId);
    QString start();
    QString stop();
};
```

And my StorageProxy class:

```
class StorageProxy : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Core *_core;

public:
    StorageProxy(Core *core);

public slots:
    // Public slots for javascript interactions
    QString start();
    QString stop();
};
```

I've added this in the constructor of StorageProxy, but I didn't manage to access the storage member:

```
this->setObjectName("storage");
```

Is something missing in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `storage` member as a [property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/scripting.html#accessing-properties):

```
Q_PROPERTY(StorageProxy* storage READ storage)
```

For more information on what you can do with this macro, see [The Property System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html). I've given links to Qt 4.8 documentation as you are using Qt Script, which is not actively developed; see the [Scripting](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/topics-scripting.html) documentation for more information on what's available with Qt 5.1.